# WxPython Ampersand Use

Tags: python, wxpython

What is the point of using the ampersand in wxPython? I see it in almost all the tutorials. For instance, they use:

```
    menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
```

instead of:

```
    menubar.Append(fileMenu, 'File')
```

What is the difference? Should I always use the ampersand for naming?

Btw I found these examples from this famous wxPython Tutorial: http://zetcode.com/wxpython/menustoolbars/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ampersand is to define a shortcut key. In your first example (i.e. "&File"), you can use 'Ctrl-F' to access the 'File' menu item

Comment: Oh awesome... thats pretty straightforward. Does it work by the first letter that is directly in front of the ampersand?

Comment: @tabchas I think it is the letter that follows the ampersand